# NoSuchElementException while accessing a list box in a web page

Tags: python, html, selenium

I am using selenium using Python. I am trying to access a list box in a webpage, but I get the following error.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: 
Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"name","selector":"s_2_1_0_0"}
```

The HTML tags are given below for the list box am trying to access:

```
<select id="s_2_1_0_0" name="s_2_1_0_0" style="width:175px" 
onchange="chkQuickStartType(this)" id="s_2_1_0_0" tabindex="1997">
```

I have used both by name & id as shown below, but still getting above error.

```
select1 = Select(ide.find_element_by_name("s_2_1_0_0"))
select1 = Select(ide.find_element_by_id("s_2_1_0_0"))
select1.select_by_value("Track a fault")
```

Comment: The HTML tags are given below for the list box am trying to access:

<select id="s_2_1_0_0" name="s_2_1_0_0" style="width:175px" onchange="chkQuickStartType(this)" id="s_2_1_0_0" tabindex="1997">

Comment: Why is there two id="s_2_1_0_0" attribute on the <select> element? is that a typo?

Can you put the options in there as well?

Comment: is this element inside of an iframe?  You need to switch to that iframe first.

Answer (score 0):

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: 
>   Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"name","selector":"s_2_1_0_0"}

I think `name/id` attribute value for desire element is not fixed, that's why you're unable to locate.

You should try with different locator to locate same element as well. I would suggest you try using `find_element_by_css_selector()` as below :-

```
select1 = Select(ide.find_element_by_css_selector("select[onchange*='chkQuickStartType']"))
```